# bash script linux - use directory as user input parameter and copy all the subdirectories to /tmp/ folder with the same name as the input directory

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a script called `package.sh` which should:

- Use directory as input parameter (can be relative or absolute pathname)
- Recursively identify all sub directories of the input directory and recreate this structure in /tmp/. For example: for an input parameter `/home/eddy` a directory `/tmp/eddy` is created.
- All the text files and script files below the input directory should be copied to the corresponding directory in `/tmp`

I am new to bash script so I would like to get some help.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this then:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r `realpath $1` /tmp
```

this copies the dir given as the first argument, to /tmp.

But as you say you only want *.txt and *.sh files copied so this should work instead

```
#!/bin/bash
cp `find $1 -name "*.txt" | xargs realpath` /tmp
cp `find $1 -name "*.sh" | xargs realpath` /tmp
```

But this doesn't recreate the directory structure like you want so you need cpio for that

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -regextype posix-awk -regex "(.*\.txt|.*\.sh)" | cpio -pdv /tmp
```

To include the criteria that the .sh files have to have the executable flag set (skip the copy if it is not set) then we have to use two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -name "*.txt" | cpio -pdv /tmp
find $1 -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -name "*.sh" | cpio -pdv /tmp
```

Comment: i tried your command but it could only work for the current directory, is there a way to have command that can use for other directories rather than the current directory? Assuming I only run the bash file from my current directory and I want the bash file to work with other directories too

Comment: That is strange, it works fine for me. How did you execute the command? Give the exact command please.

Comment: so I put the command into a shell file `package.sh`, the shell file is in `Documents/bds/bds1/`, in `Documents` I have a folder called `Fol` which I want to move to `/tmp`. So I run `./package.sh Fol`, output is `cp: cannot stat `fol': No such file or directory`

Comment: I edited the script a bit, note the type of commas around realpath $1, they are ` ` ... not ' '. See if this works.

Comment: it doesnt work, it gave me this `./package.sh /Documents
./package.sh: line 2: realpath: command not found
cp: missing destination file operand after `/tmp'
Try `cp --help' for more information.`

Comment: and also I only want to copy .txt files and .sh files from the input folder to the corresponding folder in `/tmp` only, this command copy everything in the folder

Comment: Uhhh, you don't have the realpath program? What kind of linux is this? realpath is a part of coreutils, just like chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, cp and others. At least on Arch and Debian it is.

Comment: Ahh, ubuntu put realpath in a seperate package. Install it.

Comment: I installed but still not working. But your updated solution seems to help, thanks

Comment: how about if I only want the .txt files and the executable .sh files only (which is identified by the first line starting with #!)?

Comment: the find $1 -regextype posix-awk -regex "(.*\.txt|.*\.sh)" should find all .txt and .sh files, but do you have some .sh files that are not executables and you want to exclude them from being copied?

Comment: yes, exactly what I want to do, if i have some .sh files that are not executables, I want to exclude them from being copied

Comment: then after that I want to compress that directory in the `/tmp` using tar -czf using the same name of the directory and .tar.gz as additional suffix

Answer (score 1):

well why not just copy that directory `/home/eddy` to `/tmp`? you can use some `--exclude` flags if you use `rsync` for copying in order to filter the files you need.

Comment: you're free to run rsync in a shell script, if you like